# Unable to pass dish comments to a component using props

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am working on app the displays dishes (stored in an array) and the user clicks the one of the dishes it takes the user to the  DishDetail and each DishDetail has comment associated that needs to be displayed as well. I can display the DishDetail but I am struggling to pass and display the comments, It is giving me
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined" Can anyone help me understand what I am getting wrong. I have attached all files required. thank you in advance

MenuComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Media } from 'reactstrap' ;
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody,CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';
//import Dishdetail from './DishdetailComponent' ;

   //One way of implementign functional component
   function RenderMenuItem({dish, onClick }) {
        return (
            <Card  onClick={() => onClick(dish.id)}>
               <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
               <CardImgOverlay>
                    <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                </CardImgOverlay>
            </Card>


        )
    }     
    //Another way of implementing functional component
    const Menu = (props) => {
         // using props keyword we can use to map the array
         const menu = props.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
                 <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} onClick={props.onClick} />
                 </div>
            )

        })

        return (
          <div className="container">
              <div className="row">       
                    {menu}
              </div>  

              <div className="row">       

              </div>  
          </div>
        )

    }

export default Menu;
```

DishDetail.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Media } from 'reactstrap' ;
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody,CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

    //WE PASSED AN ARRAY CALLED 'dish' form MainComponent.js

    //============== RENDER DISH =====================
    function RenderDish({dish}) {     
        // make sure the selected dish is an existing dish
        if(dish != null) {
              return (
                <div>  
                  <Card>
                       <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                       <CardBody>
                          <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                          <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>                  
                       </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </div>
              )
        }
        else {
            return (
              <div></div>
            );
        }
    }
    //============== RENDER COMMENT =====================
   function RenderComments({comments}) {
        //Get the comments array using props keyword    
        if (comments != null){
            const comms = comments.map((comm) => {
                //format the date as "Sep 06, 2014"
                let date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
                    year:'numeric',
                    month: 'short',
                    day: '2-digit'
                }).format(new Date(Date.parse(comm.date)))

                return (
                        <ul key={comm.id} className="list-unstyled">
                            <li className="comment">{comm.comment}</li>
                            <li className="author">-- {comm.author}, {date}</li>
                        </ul>          
                    );
                })

            return (         
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">  
                        <h4>Comments</h4>
                          <div>{comms}</div>  
                    </div>
                </div>

            );
        }
        else {
            return(
                <div></div>
            )
        }


    }

   //============== RENDER DISH and COMMENT ASSOCIATED =====================

    const DishDetail = (props) => {
        return (
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                   <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">       
                      <RenderDish dish={props.dish}/>                      
                   </div> 
                   <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">                    
                        // HERE IS WHERE I HAVE A PROBLEM!!!!         
                        <RenderComments comments={props.dish.comments}/>
                   </div>           
              </div>
            </div> 

        )

    }

export default DishDetail;
```

Comment: Can you show me the dish array or object?

Comment: show where are u trying to render `DishDetail` component...

Answer (score 1):

since dish.props is null in default state, it is good to use helper function to check if dish is null then return  , else call the renderComments function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that your `props.dish` part of `props.dish.comments` of `<RenderComments comments={props.dish.comments}/>` evaluates to **undefined**

I see that you pass props to the **DishDetail** component, but I can't see somewhere in your code excerpt where **DishDetail** component is been used.

Normally you should use the component DishDetail somewhere in your code (where you  want it to appear) with props passed to it like so

> `<DishDetail dish={theDishToPassToDishDetail} />`

Also, try your best to stick to one way to define your functional component. Either use a regular function or an arrow function.

Comment: Thanks fro the comments there is MainComponent.js which glues everything together. it shown below. Also the array that has the comments to be displayed is named DISHES and is shown below:

Comment: is **shared** folder outside of the  **`src`** folder?

Answer (score 0):

MainComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';
import Menu from './MenuComponent' ;
import DishDetail from './DishDetailComponent' ;
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes' ;

//function App() 
class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props) ;

      this.state = {
        // this dishes object will be passed child component "Menu"
        dishes: DISHES,
        selectedDish: null
      }

    }

    onDishSelect(dishId) {
      //when user chooses a dish update state to "selectedDish to currebt dish"
      this.setState({ selectedDish: dishId })
      // if(this.state.selectedDish){
      //      console.log(this.state.selectedDish)
      // }
  }  

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
         <Navbar dark color="primary">
           <div className="container">
               <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
           </div>
         </Navbar>

         <Menu  dishes={this.state.dishes} 
                   onClick={ (dishId) => this.onDishSelect(dishId)}/>
         <DishDetail dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === this.state.selectedDish )[0]} />
        </div>
      );
   }
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

DISHES ARRAY:

```
export const DISHES =
    [
        {
        id: 0,
        name:'Uthappizza',
        image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        label:'Hot',
        price:'4.99',
        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 2,
            rating: 3,
            comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
            author: "Michael Jaikishan",
            date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 3,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
            author: "Ringo Starry",
            date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 4,
            rating: 2,
            comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
            author: "25 Cent",
            date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]                        },
        {
        id: 1,
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **MenuComponent.js** file, you must include `<DishDetail selectedDish={this.state.selectedDish}/>` somewhere in your code, so that the selectedDish (or whatever your variable is) can be passed to the **DishDetail** class in **DishDetail.js** file as a prop.
You may refer to the below code files.

MenuComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent.js';
class Menu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedDish: null
        };
        console.log('Menu component constructor is invoked');
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Menu component componentDidMount is invoked');
    }

    onDishSelect(dish) {
        this.setState({ selectedDish: dish });
    }

    render() {
        const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {

            return (
                <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <Card onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
                        <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                        <CardImgOverlay>
                            <CardTitle><strong>{dish.name}</strong></CardTitle>
                        </CardImgOverlay>
                    </Card>
                </div>
            );

        });

        console.log('Menu component render is invoked');


        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {menu}
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <DishDetail selectedDish={this.state.selectedDish} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }


}

export default Menu;
```

DishdetailComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

class DishDetail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    renderDish(dish) {
        if (dish != null)
            return (
                <Card className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                        <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            );
        else
            return (
                <div></div>
            );
    }
    renderComments(array) {
        if (array.length != 0) {
            return (
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <h4>Comments</h4>
                    {array.map(comment => (
                        <ul className="list-unstyled">
                            <li>
                                <p>{comment.comment}</p>
                                <p>-- {comment.author} , {comment.date}</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    )
                    )}
                </div>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div></div>
            );

        }
    }
    render() {
        let dish;
        if (this.props.selectedDish) {
            dish = (
                <div className="row">
                    {this.renderDish(this.props.selectedDish)}
                    {this.renderComments(this.props.selectedDish.comments)}
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            dish = <div></div>
        }
        return (
            <div className="container">
                {dish}
            </div>
        );
    }



}

export default DishDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

from my practice, **You should send dish.comments to onClick, not only dish.id**

Menu Component.js

```
function RenderMenuItem({dish, onClick }) {
    return (
        <Card  onClick={() => onClick(dish.id, dish.comments)}>
           <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
           <CardImgOverlay>
                <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            </CardImgOverlay>
        </Card>


    )
}
```

And MainComponent.js

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dishes: DISHES,
        selectedDish: null,
        comments: null
    };
  }

  onDishSelect(dishId,dishComments) {
    this.setState({ selectedDish: dishId});
    this.setState({ comments: dishComments});
  }

<Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} onClick={(dishId,dishComments) => this.onDishSelect(dishId,dishComments)} />
```

And DishDetail.js

```
const  DishDetail = (props) => {

  return (
         <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
              <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                <RenderDish dish={props.dish} />
              </div>
              <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                <RenderComments comments={props.comments} />
              </div>
          </div>
          </div>
    );
  
}
```